# Can I insert data in Firebase database with multiple children?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can I insert data into my Firebase database with multiples children? Can I have like this JSON example where there are 2 children of the phones?

```
{
  "person1": {
    "id": 12345,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "phones": {
      "home": "800-123-4567",
      "mobile": "877-123-1234"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, why not? You can write to database like these (For Android):-

```
mDatabase.child("person1").child("phones").child("home").setValue("800-123-4567");

mDatabase.child("person1").child("phones").child("mobile").setValue("877-123-1234");
```